# data set: This engine does not support the REPLACE option

Tags: sas, teradata, 4gl

```
data ABC.TABLE_1 (REPLACE=YES);
set ABC.TABLE_1 (OBS=0);
run;

ERROR: The TERADATA table TABLE_1 has been opened for OUTPUT. This table already exists, or there is a name 
       conflict with an existing object. This table will not be replaced. This engine does not support the REPLACE option.
```

What is wrong?

Thanks,
aola

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong.  The name you want to use already exists, youu try to use REPLACE, but it's not supported.  Try dropping the original yourself, or use a name that doesn't conflict with an existing name....

Comment: I need the same name. I can dropping the orginal table, but SAS only has 2 types, strings and doubles (SAS -> Teradata). 
For example I have in the table the ID column in format INTEGER . I use proc append, but when I check the table I have ID in double or float format.
I have problem then I can use proc sql delete from but is ineffective.

Comment: Have you considered submitting the CREATE TABLE statement yourself using the EXECUTE() function in PROC SQL, via push-down to Teradata?

Answer (score 1):

Either delete the table yourself.

```
proc delete data=ABC.TABLE_1 ; run;
```

or

```
proc sql; drop table ABC.TABLE_T; quit;
```

Or if you don't want to delete the table the just remove the observations.

```
proc sql; delete from ABC.TABLE_T; quit;
```

Then use PROC APPEND to add the data to the existing table.

```
proc append base=ABC.TABLE_1 data=WORK.TABLE_1; run;
```

Note that if you want to tell Teradata what type to use can use the DBTYPE dataset option.

```
data ABC.TABLE_1 (dbtype=(id='integer'));
  set table_1;
run;
```